# Python - traceroute and store result

Tags: python

I need to perform a simple traceroute and store the results in a list for further functions.

ive found a few things online, some people right full scripts on python and some use a subprocess, i thought the latter would be easier, so i tried a simple script i found

code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys

def tracer(host=None):
    p = Popen(['traceroute', host], stdout=PIPE)
    while True:
        try:
            line = p.stdout.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            print (line.rstrip())
        except:
            break

tracer('8.8.8.8')
```

however im getting a child exception

```
>>> tracer('8.8.8.8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 2, in tracer
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>>>
```

is using subprocess the easiest way or should i use a script?

Thanks

Comment: Does `traceroute` command works in terminal? Also please show your `PATH` env variable.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to traceroute?

Comment: In addition, maybe you would ike to use native python traceroute implementation: https://gist.github.com/pnc/502451

Comment: You may need to add `shell=True` to your subprocess call. (Though note, it *can* be a security hole)

Comment: bah! traceroute wasnt installed...

Answer (score 0):

````
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys

def tracer(host=None):
    p = Popen(['tracert', host], stdout=PIPE)
    while True:
        try:
            line = p.stdout.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            print (line.rstrip())
        except:
            break

tracer('8.8.8.8')```
had the same issue i changed once bit because the code was made for linux systems and you are using a windows system
````

Comment: Hi there.. :) Add some explanation to your code perhaps? That will improve the quality of the answer...